# Header Not Loading in XHTML

Tags: html, xml, frontend, xhtml

So I am experimenting with XHTML because I wanted a break from learning PHP. I already know HTML, CSS, and JavaScript. But I just wanted to experiment with some of the other languages like SCSS. So anyway, I was running my first website in XHTML, but for some reason the `<h1>` tag would not work and just loaded it like a regular page. Anyway here is the source:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"

"https://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xml:lang="en" lang="en" xmlns="https://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <title>XHTML not HTML</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>XHTML not HTML</h1>
  <p>XHTML has always existed alongside html as an alternative for those who want the best out of both XML and HTML. So far XHTML5 is under way so lots of XHTML is more similar to HTML4 than HTML5. That said it is better than HTML, just until XHTML5 comes out nobody will be using it. If you know html already you already know most of XHTML. And will not find it difficult to learn XML. If you know CSS, you will not find it very difficult to learn SCSS. and If you know JavaScript, you will have some good background knowledge, that will make it easier to learn TypeScript, and CoffeeScript.</p>
</body>
<html>
```

Comment: try https://validator.w3.org/check
Your code has 7 errors

Comment: @vanowm Thank you, I am pretty good with html. Just the xhtml syntax is kind of confusing.